# search column 2 in csv file for value, if value, then insert "invalid" and shift cells right

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, columns

I have csv file that is auto generated by a script but for some of the records (line items) received I need to search column 2 and if the values contains "*.app" I need to print "INVALID" into column 2 for all records matching and shift cells to the right.

Example Data File:

```
   DOM,PROJ,APP,USER,DATE,TIME,STATUS
   www,test,biz.app,bob,6-1-18,09:33,OK   //Example of good line    
   www,biz.app,tony,7-11-17,06:22,ok      //Example of bad line
   ...

   Wanted output:
   DOM,PROJ,APP,USER,DATE,TIME,STATUS
   www,test,biz.app,bob,6-1-18,09:33,OK     
   www,INVALID,biz.app,tony,7-11-17,06:22,ok   //Example of fixed line
   ...
```

I have unsuccessfully tried awk, sed, and if statement but not getting the results I need

```
    e.g.

    if [ awk -F',' '{ print $2 } < FILE' ] == "*.app" ; then ; echo "INVALID"; fi
```

Which is obviously terrible... New to bash thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '$2 ~ /\.app$/ { for (i = NF + 1; i > 2; --i) $i = $(i-1); $2 = "INVALID" } 1' file >newfile
```

This would create `newfile` from `file`.  The `awk` command sets both the input and output field delimiter to a comma, then tests the value of column two against a regular expression which matches the string `.app` at the end of the value.  If the test succeeds, the record's fields are shifted right one step to make place for the string `INVALID` as the new second field.

The trailing `1` could be replaced by `{ print }` (it causes every line to be outputted).

With the given example data, the output file would contain

```
DOM,PROJ,APP,USER,DATE,TIME,STATUS
www,test,biz.app,bob,6-1-18,09:33,OK
www,INVALID,biz.app,tony,7-11-17,06:22,ok
```

Comment: Thanks so much Kusalananda, this works great!  Can you tell me how to modify this command so that when the value ".app" is found in column 2 it does not shift the cells right but rather replaces .app with INVALID?

Comment: @SSDdude Just remove the `for` loop: `{ $2 = "INVALID" }`. Keep the rest as is.

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand... if I remove { $2 = "INVALID" } how will the code replace .app with INVALID?

Comment: @SSDdude No, that's what you are left with if you remove the `for` loop.  The complete command: `awk -F, -vOFS=, '$2 ~ /\.app$/ { $2 = "INVALID } 1'`

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "," }NR > 1 && $2 ~ /.*\.app/{ $2 = "INVALID" OFS $2 }1' file
```

- `NR > 1 && $2 ~ /.*\.app/` - if record number is greater than `1` (all but first) and the 2nd field `$2` matchs the pattern `/.*\.app/`

The output:

```
DOM,PROJ,APP,USER,DATE,TIME,STATUS
www,test,biz.app,bob,6-1-18,09:33,OK   
www,INVALID,biz.app,tony,7-11-17,06:22,ok
```

Comment: Hey Roman thanks for the answer but this doesn't shift biz.app to the right it replaces the value with INVALD but does not align the other columns.  Any idea how I can do this?  Thanks!

Comment: @SSDdude, see my update

Comment: Hey Roman thanks again... this works great for everything but the first record (new test had bad line as first line).. I tried modifying your awk statement but couldn't figure out how to NOT IGNORE the first records if the second cell contains .app... Thoughts?  THANKS!

Comment: @SSDdude, your new conditions seem to be unclear. My approach provides the current expected output. Extend your question with full input fragment and respective output.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `GNU sed` tool we can approach this problem as follows:

```
 sed -e '
    1!s/,/\n&/2
    /\.app\n/s/,/,INVALID,/
    s/\n//
 '  file.csv
```

To be read as:

```
 ° Only for lines that are not the first, meaning, skip the header from being considered for processing, whilst for the others, place a marker at the second occurrence of the comma.
 ° Any line that has the 2nd field terminating in a .app append the string INVALID after the first field.
 ° Now take away the marker.
 ° N. B.  Lines whose 2nd field doesn't comprise *.app  are passed on unmodified.
```